# Testing android scala project

Tags: android, unit-testing, scala, noclassdeffounderror

Has anyone discovered already how to test Android projects written in scala?
I still got NoClassDefFoundError even when I'm just declaring scala object.

What is more, some of my activities are written in Java and they are fully testable.

I'm testing with Android Junit Test Case in Java.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is my stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PACKAGE.DataBaseManager
at PACKAGE.TESTING_CLASS.setUp(TESTING_CLASS.java:16)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:177)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1619)
```

My TESTING_CLASS is simple

```
private DataBaseInterface database;

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    if (database == null) {
        database = new DataBaseManager(mContext);
    }
}

@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
    mContext.deleteDatabase(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME());
    database = null;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide precise error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone will have this problem in the future it's enough to add AndroidProguardScala Nature additionally to your main and test project.